# Is my ISP blocking SSH? "connection timed out"

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, internet

Recently I changed ISP(and router with it). SSH used to work perfectly fine on my ubuntu-server vm, but since the switch, I only get "connection timed out", no matter which port I have the server listen to The problem persists on any VM I create.

I have installed openSSH on my ubuntu server. I have ufw disabled, and the ssh port is 3333 (set in sshd_config). The ubuntu server is on virtualbox and set up as bridged adapter.

Comment: Is your SSH port setup on your router and forwarded to the IP address of the VM?

Comment: @Terrance While making this port forwarding rule, I set the original port to 22, protocol to 'both', fwrd to addr "my server's IP', and fwrd to port 22. But nothing changed

Comment: Please include information like this in your question.  Also include the version of Ubuntu that you are using.  Also, have you contacted your ISP if they are blocking SSH or not?

Comment: If the TCP packets are getting corrupted you could easily run into this issue. See https://mina.naguib.ca/blog/2012/10/22/the-little-ssh-that-sometimes-couldnt.html on how to troubleshoot timeout connection problems by looking at the raw TCP dump

Comment: Also veirfy that port forward works at all with something simple, like telnet. It wouldn't be the 1st time an ISP modifies router firmware with their own & completely break the port forwarding interface, where the UI works but it doesn't do anything. You could also try opening the port using upnpc

Comment: Ah! You forgot to specify whether you're wired or wifi. And wether the problem is over WAN or LAN. This is important, for example modern routers have an option called AP isolation where wifi clients can't see each other at all; so you have to disable it if you're running a server and want to acces it in the LAN